# Create subscription for multiple sns topics with email list

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I'm dynamically creating multiple SNS topics based on naming conventions. I'm trying to subscribe multiple people to each topic, but I can only use one `for_each` or `count` field. How can I solve this without hardcoding multiple resources?

`variables.tf`

```
variable "system" {
  default = ["1", "2"]
}

variable "alert_level" {
  default = ["error", "exception", "info", "warning"]
}

variable "email_subscription" {
  default = ["a@company.com", "b@company.com"]
}
```

`sns.tf`

```
locals {
  alerts = flatten([
    for source in var.system:
    formatlist("%s-%s", source, var.alert_level)
  ])
}

resource "aws_sns_topic" "alerts" {
  count             = length(local.alerts)
  name              = "${var.BASENAME}-${var.ENVIRONMENT}-${local.alerts[count.index]}"
}

resource "aws_sns_topic_subscription" "sns-topic" {
  count     = length(local.alerts)
  topic_arn = "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:123:${var.BASENAME}-${var.ENVIRONMENT}-${local.alerts[count.index]}"
  protocol  = "email"
  endpoint  = var.email_subscription # how can I loop over var.email_subscription?
}
```

Comment: So for each of the alert levels a mail should go to which address?

Comment: All levels should go to all emails or in other word: everyone in my email list should be subscribed to all topics.

Comment: Ok, so e.g., `"1-error"` etc. should go to `a@company.com` and `b@company.com` or only `"2-error"` should go to `b@company.com`?

Comment: `1-error` should go to `a@company.com` and `b@company.com`; `2-error` should also go to `a@company.com` and `b@company.com`;

Comment: Ah, ok, let me think about it.

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/

Comment: I didn't include a picture...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `setproduct()` which gives you all combinations of the given sets (Docs: https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/setproduct)

And then iterate over the result of `setproduct(var.alert_level, var.email_subscription)` to create your topics. Here how it would look like:

```
locals {
  product = setproduct(var.alert_level, var.email_subscription)
}

resource "aws_sns_topic_subscription" "sns-topic" {
  count     = length(local.product)
  topic_arn = "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:111122223333:${var.BASENAME}-${var.ENVIRONMENT}-${local.product[count.index][0]}"
  protocol  = "email"
  endpoint  = local.product[count.index][1]
}
```